# REGEX expression generation

Tags: apex, validation-rule, regular-expressions, text

I have to restrict below entries by REGEX function in validation rule. Please let me know how to do that. I am unable to replicate the case. I need to put that part in below Validation Rule.

**String formats to restrict**

```
P O B
POB
P OB
PO B
```

**Validation Rule existing**

```
AND(OR(REGEX(Name,".*(?i)(p[. ]?o([. ]?|st[ ]?office))[. ]?box.*")), 
NOT(ISPICKVAL(Address_Type_abv__c,"Mailing")))
```

Comment: these value are POB or this is any type of pattern?

Comment: Just values. any combinations of P , O , B togetherly placed with spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From using [GSkinner's](http://regexr.com/) site, here's what I've come up with for your RegEx expression that captured P O and B in any combination (in that order) with or without a space between them as you show in your question:

```
([POB] )|(P?O?B(){1})
```

If you want to ignore case, and an `(i)` to the front of the capture groups as below:

```
(i)([POB] )|(P?O?B(){1})
```